# OKTA Logout SAML App

Tags: saml-2.0, logout, okta

I have setup an Application that's is using OKTA as IDP.  The app is SAML Based.This part is working fine.

But I am unable to log out. For this we have 
1. Enabled Single Logout
2. Set the Single Log out URL (I received this from Metadata of IDP under header Identity Provider Single Logout URL)
3.Sp Issues (I received this from Metadata of IDP under header Identity Provider Issuer )
4. Signature Certificate (This is the certificate of IDP)

Now when I **call the Logout URL I am receiving 403**. On checking the Logs of OKTA I see the (User Single Sign out from App Failure:- **Malformed Request**)

Can any one please help me how to fix it. 
I am assuming that I just need to call the logout URL and the session will kill off. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I suggest you debug your logout request XML with the OneLogin's SAML tool https://www.samltool.com/validate_logout_req.php
In some cases, it gives more details about what's wrong in the request payload

Answer (score 0):

Reviving a very old thread, check that you have a `?ReturnTo=<path>` at the end of the logout URL.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Brendon, Probably that was the reason. But I don't remember the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

Okta requires strictly post binding requests for logout. Please make sure you are making POST requests for logout and you are using correct entity Id in request.

Answer (score -1):

I think the setting values below need to be set for sp side.

2. Set the Single Log out URL
3. Sp Issues
4. Signature Certificate

It is not on idp side.