# SAML2 SLO integration with OKTA, hitting Malformed Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, saml-2.0, logout

I am facing difficulty implementing SLO, hitting "Malformed Request" error from Okta [Error 403].
[OKTA System Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnpeg.png).

On debug, error started on the unbinding in AuthController.

[SingleLogout error: ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2BindingException: HTTP Form does not contain SAMLRequest]

I used the following 3 codes for Logout, SingleLogout and LoggedOut found at the bottom of the page.

Similar setup as link:
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp

[Service Provider]

_Layout

```
<form class="form-inline" asp-controller="Auth" asp-action="Logout">
    <button type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

AuthController

```
[HttpPost("Logout")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout() 
{
  ...... // as per link mentioned
  return binding.Bind(saml2LogoutRequest).ToActionResult();
}

[Route("LoggedOut")]
public IActionResult LoggedOut()
{
  ...... // as per link mentioned
  return Redirect(Url.Content("~/"));
}

[Route("SingleLogout")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SingleLogout()
{
  ...... // as per link mentioned
  requestBinding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), logoutRequest); // Error at Unbind
  ...... // as per link mentioned

  return responsebinding.Bind(saml2LogoutResponse).ToActionResult();
}
```

Startup

```
services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(saml2Configuration => {
  saml2Configuration.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(saml2Configuration.Issuer);
  EntityDescriptor entityDescriptor = new EntityDescriptor();
  entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(Configuration["Saml2:IdPMetadata"]));
  if (entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor != null) {
    saml2Configuration.SingleSignOnDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices.First().Location;
    saml2Configuration.SingleLogoutDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleLogoutServices.First().Location;
    saml2Configuration.SignatureValidationCertificates
            .AddRange(entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SigningCertificates);
     } else {
        throw new Exception("IdPSsoDescriptor not loaded from metadata.");
     }
  });
```

Appsettings.json

```
"Saml2": {
  "IdPMetadata": "https://dev-00159484.okta.com/app/exk1hb8d9uOnEZoCd5d7/sso/saml/metadata",
  "Issuer": "SAML_TEST",
  "SignatureAlgorithm": "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256",
  "SigningCertificateFile": "Logs\\MyServer.pfx",
  "SigningCertificatePassword": "password",
  "CertificateValidationMode": "ChainTrust",
  "RevocationMode": "NoCheck"
}
```

XML Logout request

```
<saml2p:LogoutRequest
  xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
  xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
  ID="_a6bc814d-f94d-4226-9411-1e6db8a02571" 
  Version="2.0" 
  IssueInstant="2021-11-01T07:56:26.997Z" 
  Destination="https://dev-00159484.okta.com/app/dev-00159484_samltest_1/exk1hb8d9uOnEZoCd5d7/slo/saml" 
  NotOnOrAfter="2021-11-01T08:06:26.997Z">
  <saml2:Issuer>SAML_TEST</saml2:Issuer>
  <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">Newbie@email.com</saml2:NameID>
  <saml2p:SessionIndex>_3d179409-2239-46c8-8d55-2ac811931dc4</saml2p:SessionIndex>
</saml2p:LogoutRequest>
```

XML SingleLogout request

```
<saml2p:LogoutRequest 
  xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
  xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
  ID="_4970c041-f071-4ed8-9fad-f79221abf703" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2021-11-01T02:51:34.877Z" 
  Destination="https://dev-00159484.okta.com/app/dev-00159484_samltest_1/exk1hb8d9uOnEZoCd5d7/slo/saml" NotOnOrAfter="2021-11-01T03:01:34.877Z">
  <saml2:Issuer>SAML_TEST</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:LogoutRequest>
```

XML Logout Response

```
<saml2p:LogoutResponse 
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
    xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
    ID="_0dfec8db-eb58-4425-bb73-713e4a8a7b26" 
    Version="2.0" 
  IssueInstant="2021-11-01T02:51:35.019Z" 
  Destination="https://dev-00159484.okta.com/app/dev-00159484_samltest_1/exk1hb8d9uOnEZoCd5d7/slo/saml" 
  InResponseTo="_4970c041-f071-4ed8-9fad-f79221abf703">
  <saml2:Issuer>SAML_TEST</saml2:Issuer>
  <saml2p:Status>
    <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:RequestDenied" />
  </saml2p:Status>
</saml2p:LogoutResponse>
```

[Identity Provider]

[Okta SSO Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TkOs.png) and [Okta SLO Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZoVf.png)

Things tried:

https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test Could not reach into SingleLogout Route.

1. Launched TestIdpCore and TestWebAppCore.
2. Clicked Login on TestWebAppCore.
3. Set Debugger on SingleLogout.
4. Clicked Logout on TestWebAppCore.

[OKTA Logout SAML App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320832/okta-logout-saml-app) No further information found.

https://www.samltool.com/validate_logout_req.php Hit the error: Invalid SAML Logout Request. Not match the saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd

I have been stuck for days, appreciate any help rendered!

Answer (score 0):

You LogoutRequest appears to be missing some fields:

Namely: NameID who is being logged out?  Should be the NameID from the AuthnRequest Response.  The SessionIndex from the assertion is also good to add as it will logout only that session if supported.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                     xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                     IssueInstant="2021-11-07T02:31:35Z"
                     Destination="https://dev-00159484.okta.com/app/dev-00159484_samltest_1/exk1hb8d9uOnEZoCd5d7/slo/saml"
                     Version="2.0"
                     ID="NETSAML2_e4b4513d60a464508c75e311cf8e4215">
  <saml:Issuer>SAML_TEST</saml:Issuer>
  <saml:NameID NameQualifier="https://dev-00159484.okta.com/app/dev-00159484_samltest_1/exk1hb8d9uOnEZoCd5d7/slo/saml"
               Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"
               SPNameQualifier="SAML_TEST">timlegge@wherver.com</saml:NameID>
  <samlp:SessionIndex>59cd6620-8c9d-48a6-b4cc-8f63413f9f68</samlp:SessionIndex>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

Comment: Apologies, I made an amendment to the post for the XML logout requests. The LogoutRequest was sent in the HttpPost Logout which includes both NameID and SessionIndex. At this point i believe the session is still not deleted on the IdP side until the LogoutResponse is sent back to IdP. The unbind hit an exception on the "SingleLogout" method. [SingleLogout error: ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2BindingException: HTTP Form does not contain SAMLRequest]. The SingleLogOut request XML is when I was troubleshooting on the Saml2LogoutRequest.

Comment: Weird - I was looking at it tonight and all of a sudden the request started to validate fine.  Not sure why